# How to find a specific variable in an equation but with subtraction

Tags: python, sympy

So from searching online I have found a program that works well and reduces my current code by over 80 lines.

```
import sympy as sp    

P, V, n, R, T = sp.symbols('P V n R T')
IDEAL_GAS_EQUATION = P*V - n*R*T   

def f(x, values_dct, eq_lst):
    lst = []
    lst += eq_lst
    for i, j in values_dct.items():
        lst.append(sp.Eq(i, j))
    try:
        return sp.solve(lst)[0][x]
    except IndexError:
        print('This equation has no solutions.')
```

But `-` is used as an equal sign. I actually have a few functions that include addition and subtraction and from my experimentation any `+` or `-` sign after the first is reversed so instead of adding it subtracts and vice-versa. Is there a way around this that won't involve me completely taking this code apart?
How I have modified this program is as so.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
# declaring symbols
V, I, Ω = symbols('V A Ω')
# declaring equations
ohms_law = V - I*Ω
# list of all equations
equ_lst = [ohms_law]
# list of all vars
var_lst = [V, I, Ω]
# dictionary that stores vars and their values
var_dict = {}
# solving function
def f(x, values_dct, eq_lst):
    lst = []
    lst += eq_lst
    for i, j in values_dct.items():
        lst.append(Eq(i, j))
    try:
        return solve(lst)[0][x]
    except IndexError:
        print('This equation has no solutions.')
# getting known variables
for key in var_lst:
  tempvar1 = input(str(key) + ': ')
  if tempvar1 != '':
    var_dict[key] = tempvar1
  print (var_dict)
# Solve for unknown variables
for key in var_lst:
  if key not in var_dict:
    f(key, var_dict, equ_lst)
```

This particular program isn't going to have an equation that includes minus as far as i know but another program that isn't modified yet to use this function has an equation like that. how do I side step this or do I have to make a new function?

Comment: What do you mean by "- is used as an equal sign"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you've got PV - nRT expressed this way because you need the expression to equal zero in order to use `solve()`?
Generally, we'd say PV = nRT, but subtracting nRT leaves PV - nRT = 0, and it looks like you've done the same for Ohm's Law.

Thus my observation isn't so much that you're using "-" as "=" but that you're rearranging an equation to equal zero.
ie use property `a = b iff a-b = 0`

So am I stating your issue correctly in suggesting that you can't rearrange your equation such that f(x,y,z)=0? I believe you can't use `solve()` to solve an equation that is not equal to zero.

Otherwise, that should be an ideal solution, for which you can use the same method as you've shown. If you share the equation you want to use, we might be able to assist.

Comment: well, i never thought of that. I can't believe that i didn't notice that so thanks!

Comment: Welcome, I should add that it ought to work the same way with nRT - PV as with PV - nRT, that might have been clearer.

Comment: Actually i have another particular question. I added 2 equations to solve for power, power = P-A*V and power2 = P-(A**2)*Ω. when i input 0.02 for A and 500 for Ω it either gives me 0 volts with no power equations or an error with the new equations. why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I evaluate it with simple arithmetic, without the Ohm symbol ie `A=0.02 //
R=500 //
V=A*R //
power = A*V //
power2 =(A**2)*R //
print (power) //
print (power2)` I get returns of 0.2 for P in both cases. I'm just starting to learn python, but when I saw your question I recognised what happening on the math side such that one might assume the `-` was being used as an equals sign. Then I googled `solve()` to confirm my assumption.

Comment: Do you have an equation set to evaluate V = IR // V = IΩ? That would throw an error, or if you're assigning a value for V before defining I, Ω. My other suggestion would be to look into Ω and if that would be affecting in unrealised ways (why don't you just use `R`?), or a rounding/integer/float/decimal issue, as when I run `print 1/5` it returns `0`. I don't understand what's going on under the hood in `solve()` to help you there, I'm sorry!

Comment: Hmm well the online IDLE i am using is offline right now. I will see if using Ω is affecting it once it is back up. Thanks for the suggestion though!